# Will joins work in hibernate if the tables participating in the join are not mapped as entities in hibernate configuration?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller, entity

Let's suppose, am having two tables in my database and i have to write a join query using two tables. I mapped one of those tables as entity class in my MVC project, but there is no mapping for the other table as entity. 
so when i run hql, will that join work?

if it doesn't, and if its necessary to have a mapping, should i specify the constraints (primary/foreign key) between those entities?

My application just reads the data from tables, hence i don't want to waste much time writing entity classes. Is there any easy approach using hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate only knows what is there in session factory. If you have not defined some entity Hibernate would never know about is, so there is no question about writting hql involving that entity.

Alternatively you can get a connection from the session and then execute custom sql rather than hql.

To use plain sql you can use something like:

getSession().doWork(new Work() {

```
        @Override
        public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

About your question: HQL only works with mapped entity, but can return not-mapped object with ResultTranformer, but is not your case. You can create minimal definition of unwanted entity with just relationships and property needed by your hql.
Another way to resolve is create the plain SQL query and return only mapped entity with `session.createSQLQuery(yourQuerySQL).addEntity(YourMappedEntity.class).`

Comment: "Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See here for a full explanation"